# How to trigger PHP from Mysql Stored Procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I pass all the data to mysql stored procedure to saved into database with complex process. On the same time. If the data meet certain requirement an email should be trigger to client.

Is this possible?

Comment: have you considered having a 'cron' job that polls a table, say 'emails_due', every few minutes. And your stored procedure make an entry in that table? given that emails are involved a scan every few minutes would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick reference to the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

You can call it just like you'd run any other query.

Comment: i've no problem on calling stored procedure. the problem is to trigger an email when the condition is meet on the stored procedure?